# TCL: Recursively search subdirectories to source all .tcl files

Tags: tcl

I have a main TCL proc that sources tons of other tcl procs in other folders and subsequent subdirectories.  For example, in the main proc it has:

```
source $basepath/folderA/1A.tcl
source $basepath/folderA/2A.tcl
source $basepath/folderA/3A.tcl
source $basepath/folderB/1B.tcl
source $basepath/folderB/2B.tcl
source $basepath/folderB/3B.tcl
```

and it seems kind of stupid to do it that way when I always know I will source everything in folderA and folderB.  Is there a function (or simple way) that'll allow me to just source all the .tcl files in an entire folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building on ramanman's reply, heres a routine that tackles the problem using the built in TCL file commands and which works it way down the directory tree recursively.

```
# findFiles
# basedir - the directory to start looking in
# pattern - A pattern, as defined by the glob command, that the files must match
proc findFiles { basedir pattern } {

    # Fix the directory name, this ensures the directory name is in the
    # native format for the platform and contains a final directory seperator
    set basedir [string trimright [file join [file normalize $basedir] { }]]
    set fileList {}

    # Look in the current directory for matching files, -type {f r}
    # means ony readable normal files are looked at, -nocomplain stops
    # an error being thrown if the returned list is empty
    foreach fileName [glob -nocomplain -type {f r} -path $basedir $pattern] {
        lappend fileList $fileName
    }

    # Now look for any sub direcories in the current directory
    foreach dirName [glob -nocomplain -type {d  r} -path $basedir *] {
        # Recusively call the routine on the sub directory and append any
        # new files to the results
        set subDirList [findFiles $dirName $pattern]
        if { [llength $subDirList] > 0 } {
            foreach subDirFile $subDirList {
                lappend fileList $subDirFile
            }
        }
    }
    return $fileList
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Jackson.  I think we can put this all to rest now!

Comment: If you have a symbolic link that creates a cycle, you'll get the "too many nested evaluations (infinite loop?)" error.

Comment: sudo apt-get install tcllib tcl tk

Answer (score 11):

It gets trivial with tcllib on board:

```
package require fileutil
foreach file [fileutil::findByPattern $basepath *.tcl] {
    source $file
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps a little more platform independent and using builtins commands instead of piping to a process:

```
foreach script [glob [file join $basepath folderA *.tcl]] {
  source $script
}
```

Repeat for folderB.

If you have more stringent selection criteria, and don't worry about running on any other platforms, using find may be more flexible.

Comment: The only thing I noticed is that this returns an error if no files match, but admittedly I did not check what the other answer did.

Comment: use the -nocomplain option on the glob command to stop it throwing and error if an empty list is generated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
set includes [open "|find $basedir -name \*.tcl -print" r]

while { [gets $includes include] >= 0 } {
  source $include
}

close $includes
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on a previous answer, this version handles cycles created by symbolic links and in the process eliminates duplicate files due to symbolic links as well.

```
# findFiles
# basedir - the directory to start looking in
# pattern - A pattern, as defined by the glob command, that the files must match
proc findFiles {directory pattern} {

    # Fix the directory name, this ensures the directory name is in the
    # native format for the platform and contains a final directory seperator
    set directory [string trimright [file join [file normalize $directory] { }]]

    # Starting with the passed in directory, do a breadth first search for
    # subdirectories. Avoid cycles by normalizing all file paths and checking
    # for duplicates at each level.

    set directories [list]
    set parents $directory
    while {[llength $parents] > 0} {

        # Find all the children at the current level
        set children [list]
        foreach parent $parents {
            set children [concat $children [glob -nocomplain -type {d r} -path $parent *]]
        }

        # Normalize the children
        set length [llength $children]
        for {set i 0} {$i < $length} {incr i} {
            lset children $i [string trimright [file join [file normalize [lindex $children $i]] { }]]
        }

        # Make the list of children unique
        set children [lsort -unique $children]

        # Find the children that are not duplicates, use them for the next level
        set parents [list]
        foreach child $children {
            if {[lsearch -sorted $directories $child] == -1} {
                lappend parents $child
            }
        }

        # Append the next level directories to the complete list
        set directories [lsort -unique [concat $directories $parents]]
    }

    # Get all the files in the passed in directory and all its subdirectories
    set result [list]
    foreach directory $directories {
        set result [concat $result [glob -nocomplain -type {f r} -path $directory -- $pattern]]
    }

    # Normalize the filenames
    set length [llength $result]
    for {set i 0} {$i < $length} {incr i} {
        lset result $i [file normalize [lindex $result $i]]
    }

    # Return only unique filenames
    return [lsort -unique $result]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as schlenk:

```
package require Tclx
for_recursive_glob scriptName $basepath *.tcl {
    source $scriptName
}
```

If you only want folderA and folderB and not other folders under $basepath:

```
package require Tclx
for_recursive_glob scriptName [list $basepath/folderA $basepath/folderB] *.tcl {
    source $scriptName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Joseph Bui works well except that it skips files in the initial folder.

Change:

```
set directories [list]
```

To:

```
set directories [list $directory]
```

to fix

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect file names (with `*.tcl` extensions) in `$basepath` to a variable recursively with [`rglob`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/recursive%5Fglob) (requires tcl 8.5 or above):

```
redirect -variable tcls {echo [rglob $basepath *.tcl]}
```

then source them:

```
foreach eachTcl $tcls {
    source $eachTcl
}
```

I bring [`rglob`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/recursive%5Fglob) function here:

```js
proc rglob {dirlist globlist} {
        set result {}
        set recurse {}
        foreach dir $dirlist {
                if ![file isdirectory $dir] {
                        return -code error "'$dir' is not a directory"
                }
                foreach pattern $globlist {
                        lappend result {*}[glob -nocomplain -directory $dir -- $pattern]
                }
                foreach file [glob -nocomplain -directory $dir -- *] {
                        set file [file join $dir $file]
                        if [file isdirectory $file] {
                                set fileTail [file tail $file]
                                if {!($fileTail eq "." || $fileTail eq "..")} {
                                        lappend recurse $file
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        if {[llength $recurse] > 0} {
                lappend result {*}[rglob $recurse $globlist]
        }
        return $result
}
```

that is borrowed from https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/recursive%5Fglob